# Piping `cd` or `popd` output prevents changing directories?

Tags: shell, unix, process, pipe, cd

I understand that since `|` initiates a new process for the command(s) *after* the pipe, any shell command of the form `cmd | cd newdir` (where `cmd` does not change the current working directory) will leave the original process's working directory unchanged. (Not to mention that this is a bit silly since `cd` doesn't read input from stdin.)

However, on my machine (a CentOS 6 box, using `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`), it appears that the following command *also* fails to change directories:

```
cd newdir | cat
```

(Please ignore how silly it is to pipe output to cat here; I'm just trying to make a simple example.)

Why is this? Is there a way around this problem? Specifically, I'm trying to write an alias that uses `popd` but catches the output, discards stdout, and re-outputs stderr.

(For the curious, this is my current, non-working alias: `popd 2>&1 >/dev/null | toerr && lsd`. Here, `toerr` just catches stdin, outputs it to stderr, and returns the number of lines read/printed. `lsd` is a directory-name-and-contents printer that should only execute if the `popd` is successful. The reason I'm sending stderr to stdout, piping it, catching it, and re-outputting it on stderr is just to get it colored red using [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred), since my shell session isn't loaded with LD_PRELOAD, so Bash built-ins such as `popd` don't get the red-colored stderr.)

Comment: In response to whomever voted to close this because it's off-topic: first, this problem applies both to shell scripts and to interactive shell sessions; second, the problem arises in the context of writing an alias, which (especially in this case, where I've got some relatively complex logic involved) is essentially a tiny program;

Comment: third, on-topic questions about processes and subprocesses on SuperUser tend to focus more on user interaction with running processes (viewing/killing jobs, spawning processes, etc), whereas this question deals with the technical behavior of `|`, which seems more like a programming concern to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, `dash` and `ash`, each command in a pipeline runs in a subshell.

In `zsh`, `ksh`, and `bash` with `shopt -s lastpipe`, all except the last command in the pipeline run in subshells.

Since `cd` -- as well as variables, shell options, ulimits and new file descriptors -- only affects the current process, their effects will not affect the parent shell.

Examples:

```
# Doesn't change directory
cd foo | cat
pwd

# Doesn't set $bar on default bash (but does on zsh and ksh)
echo foo | read bar
echo "$bar"

# Doesn't change the ulimit
ulimit -c 10000 2>&1 | grep "not permitted"
ulimit -c
```

The same also applies to other things that generate subshells. None of the following will change the directory:

```
# Command expansion creates a subshell
echo $(cd foo); pwd

# ( .. ) creates a subshell
( cd foo ); pwd

# Backgrounding a process creates a subshell
cd foo & pwd
```

To fix it, you have to rewrite your code to run anything that affects the environment in the  main shell process.

In your particular case, you can consider using process substitution:

```
popd > /dev/null 2>   >(toerr) && lsd
```

This has the additional benefit of only running `lsd` when `popd` is successful, rather than when `toerr` is successful like your version does.

Comment: So essentially I had it backwards, since I thought that in cases when one command in a pipeline is in the current process, the *first* command is the one that's *not* in a subshell, but in fact it's the *last* command that's executed in the current process?

Comment: In any case, thanks for the alternative suggestion, and also for the other minor fixes (though I'm not sure why `2>&1` and `2>` behave differently). A minor correction, though--your version uses process substitution, not command substitution.

Comment: It's the last one (if any), yes. The difference between `2>&1 > /dev/null | toerr` and `2> >(toerr)` is mainly in avoiding the pipe. They both end up sending the command's stderr to `toerr`'s stdin.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I actually meant that I didn't immediately see the difference between `2>&1` and `2>` (I tried your example after adding the `&1`). I get it now, though--I guess I just forgot that `>(cmd)` is acting like a file name there after the `2>`.